# postgresql SELECT only some sub-keys from JSONB data type

Tags: postgresql

Given the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE test (  
  slots jsonb
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('{"0": {"tag": "abc", "info": "xyz"}, "1": {"tag": "def", "info": "uvw"}}');
```

Now I want to retrieve values for `tag` but am not interested in `info`.  If I do a basic `SELECT` I get everything:

```
SELECT slots FROM test;
{"0": {"tag": "abc", "info": "xyz"}, "1": {"tag": "def", "info": "uvw"}}
```

Whereas what I want is just:

```
{"0": {"tag": "abc"}, "1": {"tag": "def"}}
```

Yes, I can retrieve everything from the table and then take what I want from that, but I'd like to see if it's possible not to extract unwanted data in the first place.

If there is a way to retrieve only the bits I need, it would be great if this could make use of any new operators introduced in postgresql 14 (which seem much more similar to actual JSON operators, and therefore easier to interpret).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a key (or an index) from a JSON object (or, from an array) can be done with the `-` operator. But this operator can not affect sub-objects in JSON.
For example:

```
select jsonb '{"tag": "abc", "info": "xyz"}' -'info'
```

Result: `{"tag": "abc"}`